# Error when installing python package in R using reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am trying to access S&P Capital IQ's Python API to pull data for a report. However, I'm completely unfamiliar with how Python works (only used R before), so I'm hoping to get some help on how I can install the `capiq_excel` package in R using `reticulate`. For some background, I have an S&P Capital IQ subscription and I have the excel plugin loaded on my computer, which would obviously be a dependancy to get this to work.

When I try to install the package in R using the following code

```
library(reticulate)
py_install(capiq_excel)
```

I get the following error

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - capiq_excel

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


Error: one or more Python packages failed to install [error code 1]
```

Am I approaching this completely wrong? After installing the package, I would like to use the API to create dataframes in R. The documentation for the `capiq_excel` package can be found here (https://nickderobertis.github.io/capiq-excel-downloader-py/tutorial.html#overview)

TIA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## First try

library(reticulate)
py_install("capiq_excel")

## If the code above does not work try this

install_miniconda("capiq_excel")

Comment: I think that's not the best approach since `reticulate::install_miniconda()` is only for installing the conda environment but not the package itself. What you're doing with this code is creating a folder named _capiq_excel_ which conda installation inside.